# Angular dependency injection: Parent is null when compiling with AoT (Ahead of Time)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I got a directive which injects its parent directive (of the same type) in the constructor. It is using 'SkipSelf' so it will not get the directive which is defined on the component it is placed on (but up the tree on the parents).

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective {

  constructor(@SkipSelf() @Optional() public parent?: MyDirective) {
    console.log('Directive: This is my parent: ' + this.parent);
  }
}
```

Additionally I got a Component which injects the same Directive but is looking at itself (so no SkipSelf used here).

```
import {Component, Optional} from '@angular/core';
import {MyDirective} from '../directives/my-directive.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: './my-component.html'
})
export class MyComponent {

  constructor(@Optional() public parent?: MyDirective) {
    console.log('Component: This is my parent: ' + this.parent);
  }
}
```

An example-html could look something like this:

```
<div myDirective> <!-- (Directive A) does not have a parent (of course) -->
    <div>
        <div myDirective> <!-- (Directive B) gets the parent (Directive A) -->
            <my-component myDirective>
                <!-- (Directive C) myDirective gets the parent (Directive B) -->
                <!-- myComponent gets the parent directive (Directive C) -->
            </my-component>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything works as expected when I compile 'normally' with angular-cli (ng serve). Each Directive gets a reference to its parent (when there is one) and each component instance gets a reference to the directive which is defined on it.

But now I ran into a problem when compiling with the aot option (ng serve --aot). The directives still get their parent but the **component** does not. (Instead `this.parent` is `null`)

Anyone got an idea what might be the problem? Could it be a bug in angular-cli?

I am using following versions:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
node: 7.6.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/...: 4.0.1
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated angular and angular-cli and fortunately the issue is fixed.

```
@angular/cli: 1.1.1
node: 7.6.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/...: 4.2.2
@angular/cli: 1.1.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.2.2
```